# 3 weekly samples with 1 weekly metric on the same dataset- can 1 value represent 3 rows?

Tags: r

I have data that measures 3 concentrations per week. I have another dataset that measures hospitalizations for the week. Mock data attached below.

```
df <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2023-01-02", "2023-01-03", "2023-01-04", "2023-01-09", "2023-01-10", "2023-01-11")),
                 Concentration = c(.05, .04, .08, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3),
                 Weekly_Count = lubridate:::week(c("2023-01-02", "2023-01-03", "2023-01-04", "2023-01-09", "2023-01-10", "2023-01-11")))
df

        Date Concentration Weekly_Count
1 2023-01-02          0.05            1
2 2023-01-03          0.04            1
3 2023-01-04          0.08            1
4 2023-01-09          1.20            2
5 2023-01-10          1.30            2
6 2023-01-11          1.30            2 



df2 <- data.frame(Weekly_Count = c(1, 2),
                  hospitalizations = c(12, 23)) 
df2

  Weekly_Count hospitalizations
1            1               12
2            2               23
```

The problem I am having is that I need the hospitalization value of 12 to be representative of all 3 samples collected in the week- I need to figure out how to designate for all values that have a weekly_count of 1 to be 12 total hospitalizations. I merged the two data frames by the Weekly_Count var, but it tacks 12 onto each individual concentration which would be an incorrect value for total hospitalizations for the week. Is there a way to keep the individual measurements, group by the weekly_count var somehow, and have that weeks hospitalizations be representative of all measurements? This data is to be fed into a random forest model if that would guide the structure it should be taking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the 3 samples per week can be stored in its own column, keeping the individual measurements and their dates but using only one row per week. The result can then be merged with df2 to add the additional metric. Using the libraries data.table and tidyr:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)

# Convert to data.table
setDT(df)

# Add a column with measurement number
df[, measurement_number := 1:.N, by = .(Weekly_Count)]

# Pivot measurements and dates
df.wide <- pivot_wider(df, names_from="measurement_number", values_from = c("Concentration","Date"))

# Merge with df2
df.result <- merge(df.wide,df2,by="Weekly_Count")

df.result

  Weekly_Count Concentration_1 Concentration_2 Concentration_3     Date_1     Date_2     Date_3 hospitalizations
1            1            0.05            0.04            0.08 2023-01-02 2023-01-03 2023-01-04               12
2            2            1.20            1.30            1.30 2023-01-09 2023-01-10 2023-01-11               23
```

The 3 weekly samples are now stored in `df.result` with only one value for the weekly metric hospitalizations.

Comment: Thank you. I was considering pivoting the data but was unsure if that would have been the best move for the model I plan to use. Thanks again.